# How to loop over an Array and find part that is included in the Item not the whole item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parcel

I am building a weather app so I need to grab the icon that is matching the call from API. I'm using parcel and parcel dumps all the images in dist folder. I import all the images and that gives me an object which I converted in a one dimensional Array. Because Parcel gives some extra text I can't grab the proper image.
This is the array that I can see:

```
[0: "/01d.b9bbb2b9.svg" 1: "/01n.2290e7c6.svg" 2: "/02d.ac486e56.svg" 3: "/02n.259589cf.svg"]

<img src="${result.weather.icon}" alt="" class="weather--icon" />//I like to render it like this.
```

Is there a way I can loop over an array and get only the icon that is matching `result.weather.icon` ??? I need to find only the `01d` or `02d` from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't really clear what you are asking - because `[0: "/01d.b9bbb2b9.svg" 1: "/01n.2290e7c6.svg" 2: "/02d.ac486e56.svg" 3: "/02n.259589cf.svg"]` isn't a valid array.

However, presuming your array is simply the text elements then you can just use find. i.e.

```js
let data = ["/01d.b9bbb2b9.svg", "/01n.2290e7c6.svg", "/02d.ac486e56.svg", "/02n.259589cf.svg"];

let result = data.find(x => x.startsWith('/01d'));

console.log(result);
```

Here `find` is better than `filter` as find returns the first value that matches from the collection. Once it matches the value in findings, it will not check the remaining values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used .match to give me the exact match from the API response. Looks like this `let test = icons.find(x => x.match(result.weather.icon));`

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Array.prototype.filter allows you to loop through an array and test its values against a condition. It will then only return the values that have passed that test.

```js
const array = [   "/01d.b9bbb2b9.svg", "/01n.2290e7c6.svg", "/02d.ac486e56.svg", "/02n.259589cf.svg"
];

const targetVal = '01d';

const filteredArray = array.filter(image => image.includes(targetVal)
);
```

Comment: I think filter isn't the best here because it keeps checking even when a match is found - really if you want a single result, the first match, then find is a better option.

Comment: This one gives me an empty array if I use 01d or that type of search. I have to search for whole Item /01d.b9bbb2b9.svg to get a response back.